# Copying & renaming a VS solution folder and projects

Tags: visual-studio-2008

What is the best way to copy my VS solution, including its projects? I'd like to do this so I can experiment, maybe even destroy, my solution in the name of learning.

It looks like I can just copy the solution folder and rename it to the desired new name. Correct? As far as the .SLN file goes, can I just do a find and replace to repalce the old solution name with the new solution name? What about the GUIDs? Do those need to be updated as well? When are those guids used?

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

That should be it.  As long as the projects are in subfolders of the solution folder, they should use relative paths so their relative relationships will remain.  The GUIDs in the solution have to match the ProjectGuid elements in the project files, so you could change it in both places if you want but it's not necessary.